# What's the best way to impliment geo-specific email newsletters using PHPList?

Tags: php, email, geolocation, phplist

I'm looking at PHPList and wondering how I can use it to send geo-specific newsletters to my users?

These are just tests, but I have a database with 1 million geo-tagged locations. I also have 1-million test users, each with different addresses!  The idea is to combine users into groups based on their zip-code, and then calculate all geo-tagged entries with, say, 100 miles of that zip code - then somehow configure PHPList to send a unique newsletter to each zip-code group.

I'm worried about scale and I've never approached a challenge like this - so does anyone have any wisdom about how best to do this? Perhaps something better than PHPList?

Comment: I doubt this has much to do with phplist itself. It's more of a data mining problem to figure out who the recipients are. Once you've got that figured out, actually sending the emails will be the easiest part of the whole thing.

Comment: thanks Marc - yeah, it seems like I generate a list of user-related ZIP codes, then run and save a query for each zip code regarding which items are within, say, 50 miles - I'm just trying to figure out which recipes work and if anyone knows how to do this with PHPList versus some other platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close out this question, the best way to do this, in the end, was to skip using PHPList and write a custom controller instead.

It was a lot of work, but using PHPList for this was too awkward and also a lot of work, so it's better to write a custom code + controllers.